# Redimensionar bitmap sem desfocar

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou usando um código para tornar o *ImageView* circular. O problema é que preciso usar "**scaleType:centerCrop**", o que deixa a imagem *oval* em vez de *circular*, dependendo da resolução da mesma.

Tentei usar o código abaixo para redimensionar a imagem, mas acaba por perder muita qualidade. Estive pensando ao invés de redimensionar, mostrar apenas o que o *ImageView* consegue mostrar. Ou seja, se o *ImageView* tem **150px** por **150px**, irá mostrar apenas **150px/150px** da imagem, ignorando o restante. Mas não sei como posso fazer isso.

Código para redimensionar:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight){
    int Width = bm.getWidth();
    int Height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth / Width);
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight / Height);

    //Create a matrix for manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    //Resize the bitmap
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    //Recreate bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap
            ( bm, 0, 0, Width, Height, matrix, false );
    bm.recycle();

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Aqui está a classe que uso para tornar o ImageView circular:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RoundImage extends Drawable {

    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

Comment: Provavelmente está deixando a imagem oval quando a imagem tem uma das dimensões (largura ou altura) maior que a outra, você já tentou cortar a imagem para formar um quadrado perfeito antes de redimensionar? por exemplo: a imagem original era de 160px por 150px, ai vc corta na largura 5px de cada lado para ficar com 150 x 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android SDK disponibiliza a classe [RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html) que permitem obter *drawables* com os cantos arredondados.
Os seus métodos retornam um [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) que recorrendo ao método [setCornerRadius()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html#setCornerRadius%28float%29) permite definir o raio a aplicar aos cantos.

Se o drawable não for quadrado a imagem gerada será uma oval.

Este exemplo de utilização primeiro corta a imagem de forma a torná-la quadrada para que a imagem apresentada seja um circulo:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image);

//Determina o menor lado
int diameter = Math.min(src.getHeight(), src.getWidth());

//Cria um bitmap a partir do canto superior esquerdo do bitmap scr com
// com largura e altura igual a diameter 
Bitmap resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, diameter, diameter);

RoundedBitmapDrawable roundBitmap = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, resizedBitmap);
roundBitmap.setAntiAlias(true);

//Define o raio dos cantos igual a meio diâmetro
roundBitmap.setCornerRadius(diameter / 2);

//Atribui o drawable à image view
imageView.setImageDrawable(roundBitmap);
```

Notas:

- A documentação da classe [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) mostra que existe um método chamado [setCircular()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html#setCircular%28boolean%29) que, suponho, evitaria a necessidade de antes tornar a imagem quadrada para obter um circulo. No entanto, nos teste que estive a fazer, não consegui aceder a esse método(*The method setCircle() is undefined for the type RoundedBitmapDrawable*).
- Se as dimensões da *ImageView* forem menores que a imagem sugiro que veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) uma forma mais eficiente de obter o *Bitmap*.